# How to collect all available String over a given web site

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, web-scraping

I have been trying to do this in java but didn't able to achieve this. I searched over google find out four ways .
They are :

```
1. jsoup: Java HTML Parser
2. Apache Nutch
3. Chrome extension 
4. https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j   google crwler
```

Can someone guide me by using some working code.
For Example.

```
Let's say Given URL is google.com
```

then out put should be

```
Sign In
  Gmail
  Images
  Google Search
  I'm Feeling Lucky
  Google.co.in offered in
  हिन्दी
  ગુજરાતી
  About
  Privacy
  **same way other string that i can see over web page.
```

Comment: What do you mean by collect the strings? Please expand your question with more details, what you are trying achieve.

Comment: What do you have so far? Any code fragments?

Comment: @wumpz tried with example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669122/java-web-crawler-for-retreiving-google-search-results but didn't work and right now trying this one http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-nodejs

Comment: So post your not working example. Jsoup should do it. The example you posted only parses and outputs some metainfos. So you need to implement your text only output on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to extract all text using node js here is script 
First Step>> save it to a file test.html

```
var request = require('request');

var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://www.bajajallianz.com/Corp/new-index.jsp', function (error, response, html) {

  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

    console.log(html);

  }


});
```

Second Step

```
cat test.html | html-to-text > test.txt
```